# Web Start unable to load external driver

Tags: java, netbeans, java-web-start

I have a project as Java application, and it was running fine until I made it into web start.  My project relies on external library to deal with serial port and USB port.

To run this app. in DOS command:

```
java -DPropLoc=Drivers.Properties -jar myprog.jar <args>
```

In Netbeans 6.7.1 JRE 1.6u21, When select WebStart as Project Configuration, I can run the the main project but it failed to load the driver.
In the Project Properties, I have the VM Option set to `-DPropLoc="Drivers.Properties` and the driver relies on this file.
But if I do debug and with step by step, it will load the driver and thing run OK.

What is the problem with the web start launch?

This is the error I got after loading the driver:

```
Caught java.lang.NullPointerException: name can't be null while loading driver com.sun.comm.Win32Driver
javax.comm.NoSuchPortException at javax.comm.CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(CommPortIdentifier.java:105)
```

Since I don't understand why it loaded the driver when debugging in NB step by step.
But by running the main project by pressing F6, it won't load the driver. What is the difference of environment or JVM between Debug and Run.

Below is `launch.jnlp`file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<jnlp codebase="file:/C:/bit9prog/dev/NetBeansProjects/MyProg/dist/"  href="launch.jnlp" spec="1.0+">
<information>
    <title>MyProg</title>
    <vendor></vendor>
    <homepage href=""/>
    <description>MyProg</description>
    <description kind="short">MyProg</description>
<offline-allowed/>
</information>
<security>
<all-permissions/>
</security>
<resources>
<j2se version="1.6+"/>
<property name="PropLoc" value="Drivers.Properties"/> 
<jar eager="true" href="MyProg.jar" main="true"/>
<jar href="lib/comm.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/config.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/jakarta-regexp-1.4.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/log4j-1.2.14.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/swing-layout-1.0.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/trove.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/XmlUtil.jar"/>
</resources>
<application-desc main-class="MyProg">
<argument>r</argument>
<argument>.</argument>
</application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

Comment: What is the content of the JNLP file?  Have you validated it using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/)?

Comment: I never used JaNeLa! The launch.jnlp was generate by Neatbeans, and all the lib jar files were selfsigned.

Comment: Edited your post but not sure I did so correctly.  Please review the changes carefully.  Also, you might want to fill in the part where I added **(..What?)**. ;)

Comment: Thanks Andrew for your efforts. Do I have to sign the launch.jnlp file? Since after Netbeans created it, I had to modify its content and tried to run from the new launch.jnlp file instead of the original.

Comment: Since you filled in the 'what?' I realize I'm not in a position to answer this question.  I don't use Netbeans.  2 points though.  1) I never heard back whether JaNeLA gave that JNLP the 'all clear'.  2) If you launch the JNLP using Ant (Netbeans has it built-in), it puts much of the control back in your hands, and Ant is a launch technique I both know well & can provide advice on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a security issue. Because your driver is doing native access it has to be signed, and if the driver is already signed then the way that you add it to your jnlp file is slightly different.

For example with an internal library that is signed using your certificate then the entry look as follows

```
        <jar href="myLibrary.jar"/>
```

However for a resource that is signed by somebody else your entry looks like so

```
<extension href="Driver.jnlp" name="Driver" version=""/>
```

And it needs its own JNLP file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+"
codebase="{yourcodebase}" href="Driver.jnlp">
    <information>
        <title>Driver</title>
        <vendor>Driver Corporation</vendor>
    </information>
    <resources>
        <jar href="lib/TheExternalDriver.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security>
    <component-desc/>
</jnlp>
```

Comment: When building the project, Netbeans jarsigned all my jar files (selfsign checkbox checked), so the driver was signed by me. I will try your suggestion. Thanks

Comment: I only just noticed this.  Is it correct that this project uses natives (DLLs, Unix style .so etc.)?  If so, the launch file is definitely wrong, since either the natives that should be referenced using a `nativelib` element are a) not referenced b) incorrectly labelled as `jar`.  It is the 2nd element mentioned [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jws/developersguide/syntax.html#resources).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that NetBeans does not run WebStart project in the same current directory.

I'd suggest you to try to supply absolute path to the driver properties.
Additional test is try to check where is your program running, i.e. print `new File(".")`

I hope this will help.

Comment: I think Netbeans run Webstart in the project folder.

Comment: It built myprog.jar plus lib folder in project\dist. Also it created launch.jnlp and launch.html files

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the help and all-above thanks Andrew for useful feedback.
After all I was able to create my project running with Webstart. I have to scale down to load only USB driver, instead of loading both RS232 and USB drivers and have that library conflict, but strangely it was running fine as standard java application. Since I have no control of how the driver was implemented, all I have is a jar file from the driver provider. Maybe it's right that was a security issue, but I doubt about it, since I was able to selfsigned and run on local disk.