# Disable Java applet protection

Tags: java, applet, serial-port, code-access-security

I am building an applet for my online reservation system. The staff members can add money and do transactions at the back end of my system. They communicate with the system via a secured website. When they do a transaction, they are asked to input their personal code of 8 characters. I want to build an applet that reads an RFID chip from a reader I already have.

The reader is connected to the computer via USB and Windows redirects this USB to a COM port.

I have been able to build an Java class that reads in the contents of the chip when I scan one with the following code:

```
package model;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.TooManyListenersException;

import javax.comm.CommPortIdentifier;
import javax.comm.PortInUseException;
import javax.comm.SerialPort;
import javax.comm.SerialPortEvent;
import javax.comm.SerialPortEventListener;
import javax.comm.UnsupportedCommOperationException;

import view.Program;

public class Reader implements Runnable, SerialPortEventListener {
private Program program;
CommPortIdentifier portId;
InputStream inputStream;
SerialPort serialPort;
Thread readThread;

public Reader (Program program, CommPortIdentifier portId) {
    System.out.println("");

    this.program = program;

    this.portId = portId;

    try {
        serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open("SimpleReadApp", 2000);
    } catch (PortInUseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        inputStream = serialPort.getInputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        serialPort.addEventListener(this);
    } catch (TooManyListenersException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
    try {
        serialPort.setSerialPortParams(9600, SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
    } catch (UnsupportedCommOperationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    readThread = new Thread(this);
    readThread.start();
}


@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(20000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

@Override
public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
    switch (event.getEventType()) {
    case SerialPortEvent.BI:
    case SerialPortEvent.OE:
    case SerialPortEvent.FE:
    case SerialPortEvent.PE:
    case SerialPortEvent.CD:
        System.out.println("Carrier detected;");
        break;
    case SerialPortEvent.CTS:
    case SerialPortEvent.DSR:
    case SerialPortEvent.RI:
    case SerialPortEvent.OUTPUT_BUFFER_EMPTY:
        System.out.println("Output buffer empty;");
        break;
    case SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE:
        try {
            Random ran = new Random();
            int random = ran.nextInt();
            while (inputStream.available() > 0) {
                //System.out.println("Data available: " + inputStream.read());

                //int inputByte = inputStream.read();
                //byte inputByte2 = (byte) inputByte;


                System.out.println("Random " + random + " en resultaat " + Integer.toString(inputStream.read()));
                String id = Integer.toString(inputStream.read());
                program.setId(id);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        break;
    }

}

}
```

So far so good. But when I implement the class inside an applet I get the exception:

```
Caught java.lang.NullPointerException: name can't be null while loading driver com.sun.comm.Win32Driver
```

I searched the internet and I found that I can get it working in Eclipse by adding this to the init code of the applet:

```
System.setSecurityManager(null);
```

However when I run the applet inside the browser I get the following notification:

[image: Notification/exception from Java applet in browser]

Can't find the solution to this problem.

Comment: You should fix the original exception.  What's the stack trace?

Comment: Take a look at this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588581/web-start-unable-to-load-external-driver